# Creating image gallery using css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML for an image gallery :

```css
.post-gallery{
  display:flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}

.post-gallery img{
   max-width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-gallery">
  <img src="" width="300" height="500">
  <img src="" width="300" height="250">
  <img src="" width="300" height="250">
</div>
```

I have put width & height for images for demo purposes but I need the width & height of the displayed images to specify the positioning of each image in the gallery.

So what I want is something like(where in my case the big image has 300x500 and the smaller ones 300x250 and the gallery container is 600x500):

[image]

And if the first image has 600x250 and the smaller ones 300x250 to be displayed like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="column-count: 2;column-gap: 10px;width: 600px;">
    <img src="" width="300" height="500">
    <img src="" width="300" height="250">
    <img src="" width="300" height="250">
</div>
```

here `column-gap: 10px;` will be your grid space

Answer (score 0):

You can get this layout with `flex-flow: column wrap`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post-gallery {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.post-gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-gallery">
  <img src="" width="300" height="500">
  <img src="" width="300" height="250">
  <img src="" width="300" height="250">
</div>
```

Comment: It's not dynamic if the first image is with 600x250 and the smaller with 300*250 it will not work. As I mention in the question I want images width and height to dictate the position of images inside the gallery.

Comment: Could do with some more examples of the layouts you expect if the image sizes are varied. It almost sounds like you need a masonry layout if you don't know what image sizes you need to accommodate. https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a simple way using **float** property as following:

```css
.post-gallery {
    height: 500px;
    width: 600px;
}

.post-gallery img{
float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>First </h1>
<div class="post-gallery">
  <img src="" width="300" height="500">
  <img src="" width="300" height="250">
  <img src="" width="300" height="250">
</div>

<h1>Second </h1>
<div class="post-gallery">
  <img src="" width="600" height="250">
  <img src="" width="300" height="250">
  <img src="" width="300" height="250">
</div>
```